# visitor pattern and violation of encapsulation

Tags: design-patterns

```
void accept(CarElementVisitor *visitor) {
        visitor->visit(this);
    }
}
```

Here we are passing an object to a function which adds an operation to it.Here, it violates encapsulation. Is it good object oriented design ?

Comment: I feel like this should be asked here : http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: How does this violate encapsulation?

Comment: Encapsulation doesn't mean "cram everything you can inside a class even if you don't need to". I recommend reading "[How Non-Member Functions Improve Encapsulation](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/184401197)" by Scott Meyers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If one measures encapsulation by the count of functions that could be directly affected if the internals of an object changes, then the pattern *reduces* the encapsulation of `ConcreteElement` by a minimum of 1 when implementing the `Element::accept(Visitor)` interface.  Encapsulation may be decreased further if `ConcreteElement`'s interface needs to be expanded to provide operations to fulfill the functionality of `ConcreteVisitor`.

Patterns are neither inherently good nor bad, as it is often the context that results in the pattern being beneficial or a liability.  Thus, a designer should consider a pattern's intention, motivation, applicability, and consequences.  The Visitor pattern's intention is to allow new operations to be defined without changing the classes on which the operation operates.  While not guaranteed, it is possible that it *increases* the relative encapsulation for the `Element`-family compared to adding the operations to the `Element` itself.

For example, consider the case where an operation wants to check the fluid levels for `CarElement` objects.  Without a Visitor, the `CarElement` interface declares a `check_fluid_levels()` function:

```
CarElement                  { check_fluid_levels() }
Break: CarElement           { check_fluid_levels() }
WindshieldWiper: CarElement { check_fluid_levels() }
Wheel: CarElement           { check_fluid_levels() }

for e in car:
  e.check_fluid_levels()
```

While it may make sense to check the fluid level for some`CarElement`s like `Break` and `WindshieldWiper`, it likely does not make sense for all `CarElement` objects, such as `Wheel`.  Nevertheless, the relative encapsulation of `Wheel` has been decreased, due to `check_fluid_levels()` being declared on the `CarElement` interface.

On the other hand, if the Visitor pattern is used, then only the elements for which checking the fluid level makes sense will provide a `check_fluid_levels()` function.

```
CarElement                  { accept(Visitor) }
Break: CarElement           { accept(Visitor); check_fluid_levels() }
WindshieldWiper: CarElement { accept(Visitor); check_fluid_levels() }
Wheel: CarElement           { accept(Visitor) }

FluidChecker: Visitor       { ... }

FluidChecker checker
for e in car:
  e.accept(checker)
```

While the relative encapsulation decreases by 1 for the `accept()` function, the relative encapsulation scales better than adding the operation to `CarElement`.  Consider adding a new operation to check the emission levels for `CarElement`s.  In this case, none of the above `CarElement`s would provide a meaningful `check_emissions()` function.  With a Visitor, the new operation does not chance the encapsulation level; on the other hand, the encapsulation level changes if the operation is added to `CarElement`.

Here is a chart listing the count of functions with access to an `Element's` internals, using the above examples and two operations (checking fluid levels and checking emissions):

```
                CarElement         Visitor
                operations       operations
Break               2                2
WindshieldWiper     2                2
Wheel               2                1
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this violates encapsulation because the `Visitor` doesn't know the internal structure of the object being visited.

In your car example, our Car object knows that it has 4 wheels and a gasoline engine, but the visitor only knows what we tell it and not how we store our data:

```
void accept(CarElementVisitor *visitor) {

    visitor->visit(wheel_1);
    visitor->visit(wheel_2);
    visitor->visit(wheel_3);
    visitor->visit(wheel_4);

    visitor->visit(gasEngine);
}
```

Later we can change the implementation of our Car object without changing the visitor's visit calls:

```
void accept(CarElementVisitor *visitor) {
    //wheels now stored in array

    visitor->visit(wheels[0]);
    visitor->visit(wheels[1]);
    visitor->visit(wheels[2]);
    visitor->visit(wheels[3]);

    visitor->visit(gasEngine);
}
```